# Excel VBA Copy Paste issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with Excel VBA Copy Paste. Cell R7 has formula `=Max ("C77:AD81")`.

- R7 = Highest Value for Month
- F7 = Highest Value to date
- Q7 = the date F7 was achieved

What I am trying to achieve is if `R7 > F7`, copy R7 Value to F7 and change the Q7 to = today.

All I'm achieving is R7 changes to max of ("C77:AD81") and the remaining code doesn't work. My code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R7")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("R7"))
        For Each r In rng
            'Change Best Peak Flow and Date Achieved
            Select Case r.Value
            Case Is > ("F7")
            Case Range("R7").Select
            Case Range("R7").Copy
            Case Range("F7").Select
            Case Range("F7").Paste
            Case ("R7") = ("F7")
            Case Range("Q5").Select
            Range("Q5") = Today()
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End Select
        Next r
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the use of `Select Case`. I will take a look at your code in a moment.

Comment: Thank you any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, your `rng` object is only 1 cell, because you specified 1 target range of `R7`. With this being said, your `For Each...Next` statement is redundant.

I also wouldn't even use `Select Case` at all, but I will leave it in the event you later want to build off of it.

Give this a shot

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler    'Important to ensure events are reenabled
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("R7"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'Change Best Peak Flow and Date Achieved
        Select Case True
        Case r.Value > Range("F7").Value
            Range("F7") = Range("R7")
            Range("Q5") = Date
        End Select
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: The code still only updates ("R7"), ("F7") and ("Q5") don't update.

Comment: Good answer. Make sure you disable the events when you are inside the Worksheet_Change event and reenable them on exit. If you do not do so, changing a cell will trigger a recursive call to Worksheet_Change.

Comment: I think R7 needs to be copied to F7.

Comment: Thanks for the input Ioannis & SJR, you both are correct. @FatherGoose I have updated the code to reflect the issues that were presented.

Comment: The code update problem, ("R7"), ("F7") and ("Q5") don't update, still exist. Sorry people as a learner, I've obviously written some awful code.

Comment: @FatherGoose Is this placed in your sheet module? This shouldn't be in a standard module. The easiest way to check this is by right-clicking the sheet tab in the workbook itself (not VBE), then click `View Code`. If the VBE is blank, then you know it's not where it needs to be..   Also, this code will only run when you physically update the cell in `R7`. If `R7` updates automatically because it contains a formula, then you want to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event, not the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: K.Davis yes it's in the sheet module, I changed to Worksheet_Calculate in you latest re-code but now get error 424 Object Required.

Comment: K.Davis sorry forgot to add that R7 does contain formula =Max ("C77:AD81")

Answer (score 1):

My advice is not to use .select. You can program everything without a single .select. Recording and analyzing macros are very good starting point for learning VBA, but sometimes they are way too complicated. I prefer simple solutions so give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("F7") <> Range("R7") Then
    Range("F7") = Range("R7")
    Range("Q5") = Date
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
Here is the code I used.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Change Best Peak Flow and Date Achieved

If Range("R7").Value > Range("F7").Value Then
    Range("R7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("Q5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End Sub
```